# Checking consecutive characters in a string

Tags: strings, vb.net

First of all, this code will ask for a number (first) on how many test the user would like to have. Then the user will input the strings depending on how the number entered.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim inputArr As String() = input.Split(New Char() {Environment.NewLine})
    Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(inputArr(0))
    If count >= 1 And count <= 10 Then
        If txtInput.Lines.Length() - 1 <= count Then
            For x As Integer = 1 To count
                If inputArr(x).Length - 1 >= 1 And inputArr(x).Length - 1 <= 10 Then
                    Dim numDeletes = CountConsecutiveDuplicates(inputArr(x))
                    txtResult.AppendText(numDeletes & Environment.NewLine)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Hell no!")
                End If
            Next x
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Max test reached!")
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Number of cases is limited only from 1 - 10")
    End If
End Sub

Shared Function CountConsecutiveDuplicates(Of T)(input As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Int32
    Dim count As Int32 = 0
    Dim comparer = EqualityComparer(Of T).Default

    ' optimization for lists and arrays: '
    Dim listT = TryCast(input, IList(Of T))
    If listT IsNot Nothing Then
        If listT.Count <= 1 Then Return 0
        For i As Int32 = 0 To listT.Count - 2
            If comparer.Equals(listT(i), listT(i + 1)) Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next
        Return count
    End If

    If Not input.Any() Then Return 0
    Dim this As T = input.First()
    For Each item As T In input.Skip(1)
        If comparer.Equals(this, item) Then
            count += 1
        End If
        this = item
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

Here are the constraints:

- `tests >= 1` and `tests <= 10`
- `charofstring >= 1` and `charofstring <= 10`

This code will check the string that user input in a multiline textbox. For example, the input is 4 (as the test counter)(\n) AABBCCC (first string to check)(\n) AAAABBBC (2nd string to check)(\n) ... (4th string)

I need to check on the number of consecutive characters that are needed to delete until no characters are consecutive. This will be the result of the user input.

- 4 (first string because 1A 1B and 2C) - text in the parentheses not included in output
- 5 (2nd string because 3A 2B)
- ...

Is there any code that I do not need? Someone told me that I can still shorten the code I have. How can I modify this code?

- "txtInput = name of input textbox"
- "txtResult = name of output textbox"
- "Button1 = name of button to execute the code."

Answer (score 2):

By using the `Distinct` method and comparing lengths you can get the number you want in one line.  Here's what such a function could look like:

```
Function CharsToDelete(Of T)(input As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Integer
    Return input.Count - input.Distinct.Count
End Function
```

Oops missed the part about consecutive chars.  This should do the trick:

```
Function CharsToDelete(Of T)(input As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Integer
    Return input.Where(Function(x, y) x.Equals(input(y + 1))).Count
End Function
```

You don't need to split the text into an array.  The `Lines` property of the TextBox already does this:

```
Dim inputArr As String() = txtInput.Lines
```

Comment: then how can i use it in my code and what should i replace?

Comment: Ok ive tried it and it works when the user input is AABBCCCC however when user input ABABABABA the answer should be 0 because there are no consecutive but the method you gave returns a number.

Comment: @MixAustria - Oops missed the part about consecutive chars.  I added more code for you to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest a different method to find the replaceable character count of consecutive characters in a string. I will explain it with the help of code and example execution.

Consider the code:

```
Dim inputStr As String = "AAAABBBC" '<--- input string 
Dim splitArray As Char() = inputStr.ToCharArray '<--- split the string as character array
Dim replaceCount As Integer = 0 '<-- initialize the variable for counting the replaceable characters
For i As Integer = 0 To splitArray.Length - 1 '<--- take each characters in the array
     If splitArray(i) = splitArray(i + 1) Then '<--- Compare with the next immediate character if comparison gives true then increment the counter
        replaceCount += 1 '<--- increment the counter for each match
    End If
Next
MsgBox(replaceCount) '<--- will display 5 in this situation
```

If you want to perform this for number of lines then you have to place the code in a looping statement that iterates through each line.

I have another suggestion for reducing the number of replaceable characters:

Let the input string be `"AAA"` AS per this solution the number of replaceable characters are `2`. But **only one character** is enough, no? If we replace the middle character (`"AXA"`) then the output will not contains any consecutive characters, so that I can reduce the number of replaceable characters to `1`.

Coding for doing this operation:

```
Dim inputStr As String = "AAAABXXC" '<--- input string 
Dim splitArray As Char() = inputStr.ToCharArray '<-- split into array
Dim rnd As New Random '<--- generate a random number for replaceable character
Dim replaceCount As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To splitArray.Length - 2
    If splitArray(i) = splitArray(i + 1) Then
        replaceCount += 1 ' <-- increment the count 
        splitArray(i + 1) = Chr(rnd.Next(128, 200)) '<-- Replace the character with random special character
    End If
Next 
MsgBox(replaceCount) '<--- it will display 3 for this time
```